# Is Age of Empires II: The Conquerors playable on Ubuntu?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, ubuntu

Is it possible to play Age of Empires II: The Conquerors on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible to play using Wine, as shown on their website [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4184).

Comment: My personal experience with AoE under Wine 3 is that it was too choppy/laggy, to the point of being nearly unplayable.  YMMV.  However, yes it is definitely possible.

Comment: An update: I have heard anecdotally that AoE 2 works almost flawlessly under Wine 1.4, but have not verified this myself.

Answer (score 2):

My best experience of Age of Empires 1 and 2 was running a Windows 98 WM on VirtualBox.

I found Wine acceptable, but the Win 98 VM used so little resources that it was preferable to Wine.

You can use an XP VM, but you have to restart `explorer.exe` after starting the game to resolve a couple of graphics glitches (this is true of a hardware install of XP also.)

Bear in mind that the original game is from the 90's and is getting on for 20 years old. It is one of my all time favourites, but the screens were low res CRT back then - the original game will either be a smallish window or very blocky and stretched on a new monitor however you play it. On my 19" it's not too bad, but on my 26" it's just unpleasant

If this will be a problem, go for [the Steam re-release](http://store.steampowered.com/app/221380/); it's HD for modern screen resolutions. As before, run it from Windows if you can. I ran it on Wine, but at full screen I had all kinds of errors and since that's the reason you'd play that version, best use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If Wine can also run the Steam platform, then you might be able to run AoE through Steam via Wine because a HD Remake of Age of Empires 2 has been announced for Steam on April 9th.  The cost is $19.99 or $17.99 for pre-orders.

Here is the link:
http://store.steampowered.com/app/221380/

Answer (score 0):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) has streamlined the process to nearly as easy as on Windows.  My personal experience is that Age of Empires I, II, and III all work *better* on Ubuntu than they ever did on my Windows machines.